# How to type a parameter as any interface with values of a certain type in Typescript

Tags: typescript, types

I have a function that I would like to accept any interface that contains only values of type `T`. For example:

```js
// library function
function print(thing: /* any interface that is boolean | string */) {
    console.log(thing)
}

// user defined interface
interface Machine {
    powered: boolean
}

// user defined interface
interface Animal {
    sound: string
}

// user defined interface
interface Person {
    age: number
}

let blender: Machine = {
    powered: false
}

let cat: Animal = {
    sound: "meow"
}

let person: Person = {
    age: 24,
}

print(blender); // all good
print(cat);     // all good
print(person);  // nope
```

I tried a mapped type (and `Record<string, T>`), but it appears that Typescript doesn't let you cast interfaces to those. How should I type `thing` to accept any interface with values of type `boolean | string`?

Comment: I am no typescript expert, but I think this is not possible. You need to type the parameter and not the properties of the parameter. Therefore I think you need to type the parameter as "thing: Machine | Animal"

Comment: @SebastianS. `print` in my example would be a function in a library, which wouldn't know about Machine or Animal ahead of time. I've edited my q to make that more clear.

Comment: Something like [this](https://tsplay.dev/wQYRjw)? Let me know if I should write an answer.

Comment: @ghybs Yeah that's exactly what I'm looking for.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the function parameter `thing` type is `Record<string, T>`, it can accept only arguments that extend `{ [k: string]: T }`, i.e. with at least `string` [index signature](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/2/objects.html#index-signatures), which is not included in well-defined interfaces like `Animal` or `Machine`.

To accept any kind of interface with some unknown but well-defined keys (i.e. which may not have an index signature), you can use a generic parameter type that "extends its own keys":

```
function print<T extends { [K in keyof T]: string | boolean }>(thing: T) {
    console.log(thing)
}

print(blender); // all good
print(cat);     // all good
print(person);  // nope Error: Type 'number' is not assignable to type 'string | boolean'.

const rec: Record<string, string> = {}
print(rec); // Also okay
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAPAFUQUwA8p8wATAZ0QG9EBtAaUQ0QGt8BPOYRHAXQBciClHRgA5ogA+iAEZw4AG3wBDJAF8AfAAooACwzihOAJQ0AUIiuIICCkvwA6RXHG6DEk+fXnzGEqjAKhD4iACywR6h1JbWyHAA7vio+GRC8g5q3r7+yUEhiACCYDAAtiqKFtbCcOBpwqKG2X6YecGhAArJ9kgx1Sri+EJgIKWyyc3KUHLK5MlCERBRiAC8VXGJyalCQYoU+JP40xAqUELFZRWr61b2dUIARKX4iQ+H08jdCEJdqD3XfWsAyGiAATAAWAA0zTQ-m0slmZGSJgA3IgAPToxAVSriBRkcywzDaE5QVHVDFYnGIPFwAlEqDaT5-BDkymIMBwT6IACiqFQcFQxg43IA5CMxslRcwqJzpioKBQYOIwCoEaEoHBEFARaFRSIxJIZBllGpRY5fLYwCJECkIEIAEr4WyoMhYA2GSENQ2aAE+BnaO3kzFFPZauCsFQccxAA)

---

Another possibility would be to use the generic parameter type only to infer the passed argument keys:

```
function print<T>(thing: Record<keyof T , string | boolean>) {
    console.log(thing)
}
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAPAFQHwAUUAFhgOYBciASgKYRyoAmWA1rQJ5zCI4A0iAM5R0YMogA+iAEZw4AG1oBDMHgCUiAN4AoRHsQMwghbQB08uGSKkxa7QF9t2jFFqpgSiLUQBZTze8dfRQ4AHc3WiYqWRMVBycXNw8vRABBMBgAWyV5LV19Y3AooRFyeOdMJM9vAAU3YyQg-SUyWiowEEzpN3LFKBlFMCY3Kj8IAMQAXjzg5DCI4o95QVpe2n6IJSgqdKycqZmCuCKqACJM2jDTtf7keoQqOtQGg6a9FrbEACYAFj5ytAuAjSQbDVBqADciAA9NDEDlcmQ5ExtIDMARNlBIcEYXCEYgkXAUWioAQ7s8ENjcYgwHA7ogAKKoVCMKg4Dj0gDkHS6bk5iBgghpcH6SkEghgZDAShB3igcEQUA53k5wlE4ikMUUKk5pichmEiFQ9CodAYzCwavIAitYjwr0cJIIxog2NhaWWCrgrCUHG0QA)

---

The initial confusion may arise from one expecting a well-defined *interface*, like `{ powered: boolean }`, to extend `Record<string, boolean>` (same as `{ [k: string]: boolean }`), because the former has some string keys with boolean values.

That is actually true for *type alias*:

```
function print(thing: Record<string, string | boolean>) {
    console.log(thing)
}

// type instead of interface
type MachineT = {
    powered: boolean
};
const blenderT: MachineT = {
    powered: true
};
print(blenderT); // Okay
```

Works fine as well for object literals (i.e. when written directly inline):

```
print({
    sound: "meow" // Okay
});
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAFFAFhgcwC5EAlAUwjlQBMAeAZynTAIBpEmWDEAfRAEZw4AG3IBDMAD4AlIgDeAKEQrEVMA1HkAdCLgEc+VjMUBfRYoxRyqYOIjlEAWXtHHS1SjgB3G+RokQlqSZhZWNnYOiACCYDAAtuIiCsqqmuABnMyEoZaYEfaOAAo2mkgequIE5CRgIPECNrliUIJiYDQ2JC4QbogAvCmeyD5+mXYiDOTN5K0Q4lAksQlJA0NpcBkkAETx5D7bM63IpQgkJahlaxUqVTWIAEwALGy5aFZYAu2dqDIA3IgAPSAxAAUVQqGoJAAkh1yAAPTgwAhgBYgVCOYDURBQACeJ0QAHIuIRCYgYAxEPEKQxCOSkHiCYSem5CdpFO9MFh5lB-p4gSDwZDUDC4YjaSi0RjEFjUDj8Y5idlWGSKVSaXSMPKmctEiI2RyWNgTpcEHyBWCIVDELDOuLkaioOjMdjGYqSSryZTqQxaax6drFRcygbFMDA-SmBIaIg4MB6dZbIVFG7nK4MOQACrXVIqEa+DGZIJiEKmP6KFptchw1CZ7rpsBZnPDUaFkjMEDTMuGj5fas-TN88MAeQA1uJcRZOdgbpxNh0dnsDhaxxOzP9FEA)

This is a design choice by the TypeScript team.

The main rationale is that an `interface` can be [*augmented*](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/declaration-merging.html#merging-interfaces), hence it could later get extra keys with different value type.

Whereas a `type` cannot be augmented, so it can be *more safely* considered that it extends ("*implicit*") the index signature.

See [ms/TS#7059](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/7059) for all details.

---

Note that in all cases, looping over such Record keys may lead to some unexpected results in runtime, because of absence of [excess property check](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-1-6.html#stricter-object-literal-assignment-checks) during assignment of variables by another variable (whether type or interface):

```
function print(thing: Record<string, string>) {
    for (const key in thing) {
        const value = thing[key];
        //    ^? string
        console.log(key, typeof value);
        console.log(
            value.charAt(0) // Okay at compile time but... fails at runtime!
        );
    }
}

// type instead of interface
type AnimalT = {
    sound: string
};
let catT: AnimalT;

const extraAnimal = {
    sound: "roar",
    excess: 1 // Excess property...
}

catT = extraAnimal; // Fooled by no excess property check!

print(catT); // Okay but... mismatching type in runtime!
// [LOG]: "sound",  "string" 
// [LOG]: "r" 
// [LOG]: "excess",  "number" 
// [ERR]: "Executed JavaScript Failed:" 
// [ERR]: value.charAt is not a function
```

[Playground Link](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/GYVwdgxgLglg9mABABwE4zFAFFAFhgcwC5EAlAUwjlQBMAeAZynTAIBpEmWCA+ASkQBvAFCIxiYNURYqYJogDW5AJ6IMiPIQEjxuxLPkA3AIYAbEOUQBeDflYBtJcoC6AblF6xAei+6AegD8Hp4GcKbkAHSmcARYThxQysjkcMCIJubkfO6eYqHhUTFYwbliGRYRELjGqACC2AAMAj6IAPIKxqrGUPpwALbIMOEaMH2WAEYgUBEzEsZDDIjdiKjgsGMAhCW62SUAvsIHwi2JyWpyUOTGNIip55eowMYQ5MKnlrVgo2YAKtZCJQYcHANBIXEIh3c4R6EG6PxIn2+ph+7mEBh65AAHsxjIi+mZ-jpxECQSQAESoOA1MlsEpYl4MBgkACMiBaAFFMQyGIQUJTkqhEjMIodhGi4f8sTi8WZXGzfAAxOBhcg3caqMBwRD08iMvlwAWJfS4SgKLbCNAYbCwqA-bLytodVSTaazPowBj4qBVXnvc4rNajchbIA)

Comment: Thanks for the detailed answer. Do you know why TS doesn't cast interfaces to mapped types like it would `Horse` to `Animal` where `Horse extends Animal`?

Comment: Hum do you mean why `Animal` does not extend `Record<string, T>`? In that case, this highlights the difference between `interface` and `type` alias. I will explain further in the answer.